# Fazer com que o programa retorne ao começo de uma condicional caso a condição não seja true

Tags: c#

Não consigo fazer o programa repetir até que a condição seja verdadeira, sou iniciante, alguém pode me ajudar? :(

```
        Console.WriteLine("Digite sua hora de entrada");
        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite os minutos da entrada");            
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (minutes < 00 && minutes <= 60)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Minutos inválidos... Digite um valor de 0 a 60");
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        } else
        {
            string hournmin = "Sua hora de entrada foi: " + hours + "h" + minutes + "min";
            Console.WriteLine(hournmin);
        }
```

Comment: Veja se a resposta te ajuda, editei sua pergunta para descrever melhor o erro, espero que eu tenha entendido corretamente sua dúvida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque os sinais `<` por `>=` na primeira condição. Em seguida troque o local das saídas e dentro da condição troque o valor `60` por `59` já que os minutos contam a partir do zero. Sua estrutura funcionará, veja o exemplo abaixo:

C#:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Digite sua hora de entrada");
    int hours = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Digite os minutos da entrada");            
    int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (minutes >= 00 && minutes <= 59)
    {
        string hournmin = "Sua hora de entrada foi: " + hours + "h" + minutes + "min";
        Console.WriteLine(hournmin);
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Minutos inválidos... Digite um valor de 0 a 60");
        minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

De acordo com o laço acima, caso o usuário digite um valor menor que zero ou maior que 59, o laço retornará uma mensagem informando o erro.

**Adicional**

É possível melhorar a lógica usando um while, que trata melhor a condição apresentada. Veja exemplo abaixo:

C#:

```
    while (minutes < 00 || minutes > 59)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Minutos inválidos... Digite um valor de 0 a 60");
        minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    string hournmin = "Sua hora de entrada foi: " + hours + "h" + minutes + "min";
    Console.WriteLine(hournmin);
```

Ao substituir o `if` pelo `while` e alterar as condições do laço, o seu programa trata uma entrada inválida de forma mais inteligênte, reenviando para o input dos minutos até que uma entrada válida seja inserida.

Comment: Muito obrigado, sua resposta foi realmente útil!

Deixe-me perguntar: tem alguma maneira de fazer o laço se repetir caso "minutes "não seja menor ou igual a 00 e também não seja menor ou igual a 59?

A ideia era que caso o usuário colocasse um valor invalido, pedisse para ele digitar novamente outro valor

Comment: Sim, Você pode criar um While, me manda msg no linkedin que te mostro. pode encontrar meu linkedin no perfil.

Comment: Se te ajudou, não esquece de deixar marcar como resposta abaixo dos botões de votação <3

Comment: Não estou conseguindo entrar em contato com você via linkedin, você pode me mostrar como faço por aqui? Isso iria ajudar tanto. :(

Comment: adicionei na resposta, veja.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo! Passei maior tempão quebrando a cabeça, não conseguia enxergar a lógica de como fazer isso. Obrigado mesmo!!!!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105793/discussion-between-brewerton-santos-and-antonnymello).

Comment: Continuamos no chat.